# Debug.waitForDebugger(); not working in Android studio

Tags: android, debugging

When I worked with Eclipse, I used Debug.waitForDebugger() to enter debug mode in hard to reach classes like services.

However, since I moved to Android Studio, I was not able to get Debug.waitForDebugger() to work.
When I add it and run the app, it does not enter debug mode at all.

Does anyone know how to make Debug.waitForDebugger() work in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from AOSP issue 76040 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76040 -

"DDMS in Eclipse will monitor apps run on a device. When apps show up in ddms in "waiting-for-debugger" mode and the app name (its package) match the package of an app opened in the workspace, then ADT will automatically connect the debugger configured with that particular app.

We should do this in Studio as well. Probably after 1.0 though"

Up until today this problem has not been resolve yet in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

try `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

Comment: This is not an import issue... by calling Debug.waitForDebugger() I basically call android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

Answer (score 0):

Use the emulator/device entries under ["Settings>Development Options" as advised here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#debugging)